# Laravel frontend:index not found

Tags: php, laravel

i have just installed a code, and enter the page.
Then i see 500 error, i turn n debug and this come forward.

```
View [frontend.index] not found.
```

it complains about this code:

```
$model_News = News::where("status", "publish");
        $data = [
            'rows'=>$model_News->paginate(5),
            'model_category'    => NewsCategory::where("status", "publish"),
            'model_tag'         => Tag::query(),
            'model_news'        => News::where("status", "publish"),
            'breadcrumbs' => [
                ['name' => __('News'), 'url' => url("/news") ,'class' => 'active'],
            ],
            "seo_meta" => News::getSeoMetaForPageList()
        ];
        return view('News::frontend.index',$data);
    }
```

I copy a frontend from an older version and this come up then.

```
Call to undefined method Modules\News\Models\News::translateOrOrigin()
```

and this is the code, i don understand.

```
@php

        $translation = $row->translateOrOrigin(app()->getLocale()); @endphp
```

**UPPDATE:**

I reinstall everything, but now i get this error:

```
View [frontend.layouts.search.form-search] not found.
```

And in the code:

```
@include(ucfirst($service_type).'::frontend.layouts.search.form-search')
```

But i can´t find the path, Shoud i search in resources\views or?

Answer (score 0):

Check **News** Module is present in your project or not and also the view file inside there.

**Modules\News\Models\News::translateOrOrigin()** indicates that you are trying to call a method called translateOrOrigin() on a model class, in this case, **Modules\News\Models\News**, but that method is not defined for that model. This error is typically associated with a package or library that you are using for translation or localization, and it seems like the translateOrOrigin() method is missing or not available for the News model.